# python client app model comunication with a Json API

Tags: python, json, extjs, model, storage

Sorry in advice for my strange english.
I have to develop a client application with python that comunicate with a php server that uses JSON protocol for data exchange.
There are many python frameworks that permit to implement MVC pattern, and in particular with structured Models for data handling, but all these model structures talk directly with a database in SQL language.
My purpose is to use a single server that shots data with JSON api to all kind of devices or platforms.
So, in my python application, i would to write a syncing model storage that talks directly with my Json Server as well as an ExtJs 4 app, using a framework or a library that permits to implement easily my request.
Does anybody knows any tools that permits this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you're looking for a proxying solution to put between application server clients. It may not be 100% fit but I'd suggest looking at [Ext.Direct](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/extdirect) remoting that's built in Ext JS; RPC should work fine if you don't have to publish and maintain your API. As for proxying, take a look at [RPC::ExtDirect::Client](https://metacpan.org/module/RPC%3a%3aExtDirect%3a%3aClient). It's an Ext.Direct client implementation in Perl; I developed it mostly for testing purposes but it can probably be used for proxying, too.

On a side note, I'm not sure why exactly you would want to implement such an architecture at all. It sounds overcomplicated for no good purpose.